# Dropbox 'Waiting to be Linked to a Dropbox Account'

Tags: internet, proxy, dropbox

When I execute `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` after

`cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -`,

Dropbox GUI loads, on the notification bar I configured the proxy for the Application, also my environment variables http_proxy etc. are set.

Still, the GUI shows “Not connected to the Internet” while the notification icon says “Waiting to be linked to Dropbox account”.

Online Forums says `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` will also print a link on terminal to connect to Dropbox, but no such link comes, only GUI opens.

Any fixes would be appreciated.

PS: I am running Ubuntu along with Windows 7 (should not really be the cause of the problem).

Comment: This entire question and answer are obsolete -- Dropbox no longer supports an app on Ubuntu, though there's a work-around to connect a local folder to your dropbox with auto-synch.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Dropbox preferences, switch to the tab `Account` and press `Unlink This Dropbox`. After your client is unlinked, go to the Dropbox website, click on your name in the top right, and choose `Settings`. Then switch to the tab `Security`. There is a section called `Devices`. Press the `x` on the right for every computer not in use any more. When you link your client again afterwards, make sure to use a name not already listed on the website.

Since you're new to this page: Please press the tick on the left it this solves your problem.

Comment: Dropbox preferences Account tab in Ubuntu is greyed out while in Windows it is not greyed out. Earlier I thought that because Both on Ubuntu and Windows my Device name was same, it was the culrpit but I tried changing my device name but that did not help.

Comment: I tried to unlink from my Windows system. Now on Windows also I cant Relink and the same error appears :(

Comment: I tried reinstalling, by mistake installed older version. It launched and did not show no internet connection asked for username and pass and logged in but then in the last step said you are using older version of dropbox. On installing the new version same no internet connection is appearing on both windows and ubuntu now